# Giving different alignments to different items added to the same listbox

Tags: c#

Yesterday, i asked a question but i think I've not made it clear enough. So I'll try again.

I have two methods: 
One for displaying a message from a Client as an item in a listbox(lstMsg).
The other for displaying message from the sender into the same listbox.

My Problem: I want to give **the listbox item** added to my first method a **left align** and give the listbox item added to my **second method** a **right align**.

Below is the code:

```
private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
                    lstMsg.Items.Add("Client: ");

                    lstMsg.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                lstMsg.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                lstMsg.ForeColor = Color.Blue;

                lstMsg.Items.Add("You:");
        }
```

Comment: You would be better off updating/fixing/expanding "yesterday's post" rather than posting a new one.  As is, this is just a dupe.  Also please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: In my opinion, you're using the wrong control. You might be able to approximate what you want with [OwnerDraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx) but you might also be better off finding a control that is suitable for this kind of display.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WebForms or WPF?

Comment: Yes, it's WinForms